# R data.table group first,last and middle rows using rleid

Tags: r, data.table

I need to group a data table using rleid. There should be three groups. One group for first row one for last row and one for all other rows in between first and last row.

I know how to group if I have a condition. Like

`dt[,group := rleid(condition)]`

Comment: data and desired output?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a constant vector of size `nrow(dt) - 2` to get a condition to apply `rleid()` on.

```
dt[, group := rleid(c(1, rep(2, nrow(dt) - 2), 3))]
```

Comment: What is there are conditions for first and last group?

Comment: `rleid()` doesn't need a logical condition. I used the "condition" `c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, ..., 2, 2, 2, 3)`. So I made the first and last entries of that vector different from the entries in the middle (which there are `nrow(dt) - 2` of. You could also use the logical vector `c(T, rep(F, .N - 2), T)`. In this case, `.N` is the same as `nrow(dt)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a vector of all the same values then `replace` individual elements (e.g. first and last elements) with something else. The code below creates a column which is `1L` for the first row, `3L` for the last row, and `2L` otherwise.

```
df[, group := replace(rep(2L, .N), c(1L, .N), c(1L, 3L))]
```

Another way using `rleid` is

```
df[, group:= rleid(.I %in% c(1L, .N))]
```

You can also do grouping operations on variables you create, not already in the data table.

```
df <- data.table(x = runif(100))

df[, .(sumx = sum(x)), 
   .(group = replace(rep(2L, nrow(df)), c(1L, nrow(df)), c(1L, 3L)))]

#    group       sumx
# 1:     1  0.1546382
# 2:     2 48.1939765
# 3:     3  0.4710213
```